# How to re-activate archived private chatter group?

Tags: chatter-groups

I have a private chatter group that was archived.  When I try to access it, I get:

> "The requested resource does not exist" Error id: 1112177927".

After seeing this message, I do see a page where the basic chatter group
info is visible though there is no "activate" button as there was on a similar public group.

Is it possible to re-activate an archived private group?

Comment: what page are you seeing the basic chatter group info?

Comment: It's the page that gives the group's specific name, details, and owner.  No post info.

Comment: If you edit the group layout, add the "archive" field to the layout, and then uncheck that does it work?

Comment: The archived public group that I'm looking at has an "Activate Group" button along with a "This group has been archived" message.  Not sure why the private group would be different.

Answer (score 0):

This chatter group was created in a community.  It needed to be re-activated in the  community.  The chatter group is visible on the Salesforce side of things with no indicator (that I could see) of its origin in a community.

The error message was singularly unhelpful in resolving this problem.